# Move Library file generates no dialog of target folders

Tags: content-assets

Within the `Asset Libraries`, I have a list of files that I want to move to a different folder (out of the top level).

When I click `Move`, nothing happens - no list of target folders is shown, even though I can see the folders.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation typically happens when associated with the OOTB `Asset Library` that may initially be set up with only `Viewer` permission to `Internal Users`

You need to add yourself (and relevant others) as a `Library Administrator`

- Go to Asset Library and click `Manage Members`

[image]

- Assignment - find person or group, set permission, then Add

[image]